# Android Studio 2.0 Preview 2 issue with Renderscript

Tags: android, android-studio, android-renderscript

I updated Android Studio to 2.0 Preview 2, then I got an error **Renderscript support mode is not currently supported with renderscript target 21+**

I'm using renderscriptTargetApi 23

Comment: So target 21? Why do you want to target 23?

Comment: It was working before, after the update it doesn't any more, and I believe you mean target 20

Comment: did my answer work? if so accepting ti would be great because it seems to be working for others.

Comment: Sometimes It does not work when I put the minimum SDK in gradle.properties, it works only when I explicitly declare it in gradle file

Comment: use Build tools 23.0.3 and Gradle 2.1.0 (currently highest version is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Renderscript isn't currently supported with Target 21+ so simply change the target to API 20 and that should solve the error. So the renderscript related options in your default config section of your gradle file should like :

```
renderscriptTargetApi 20
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same message 
Error:Renderscript support mode is not currently supported with renderscript target 21+
although I'm using renderscriptTargetApi 20

Comment: Make sure your targetSdk is set to the same thing.

Comment: it's workaroung, not fix. targeting 23 works with build tools 23.0.3 and Gradle 2.1.0

Answer (score 10):

The bug related to `renderscriptTargetApi` has been fixed in gradle-plugin 2.1.0 and Build-Tools 23.0.3.
Please try it out:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer was for me at the bottom but is the best answer since Android fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

@atabouraya,
This is bug in build tools. Please check your build tools version and if is lower than 23.0.3, update them. 
More info here:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/revisions/build-tools.html
in Build Tools, Revision 23.0.3 (March 2016)

Comment: and this is proper answer, works with Gradle 2.1.0, currently highest dev version is alpha5: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5` . so at this moment we have to pick build system in alpha and newset supporting for renderscript or older render script with current stable version of Gradle. Waitng for final Gradle 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

@atabouraya,
There need to be change in build.gradle of your app

as suggested from [android developer site.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19

        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `renderscriptTargetApi 23` to `renderscriptTargetApi 20`, and make sure your `minSdkVersion` less than `21`.